# Cannot get C# Snippets to work in Visual Studio 2022

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2022, code-snippets

I'm not 100% sure when this started happening, but now if I type 'if' and double tab, it just puts two spaces after the if and gives me an error code saying 'Command Handler 'Snippets' has exceeded allotted timeout and was auto canceled. This happens for all snippets that in C#. I have changed the setting in Text Editor > C# > IntelliSense and made it 'Always include snippets'. I have also tried a fresh install of VS 2022. Has anyone else run into this?[image]

Comment: Try 1) Open a `Developer Command Prompt` from the start menu. 2) Run `devenv /safemode` and see if snippets work. 3) Also try [enabling logging](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/reference/log-devenv-exe) and see if there's anything that catches the eye when it fails.

Comment: Thanks, that helped me find the source of the problem!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like this was caused when we updated to the newest version of Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Memory using nuget. We were running version 5.0.0 and when we moved to 6.0.1 it caused a number of problems.